# Android: drawing concentric circles

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to write an app that connects to a remote host and reads lines of x,y tuples and draws them to a scatter plot in real time.  The data is being displayed as expected but when I modified the code to try and display some markings to measure the data it isn't working as expected.  I expected to see a black background with 20 concentric gray circles.  As data rolls in it should be displayed as green dots on the concentric circles.  Instead, what I see when the remote host is down, is that initializeSurface() is called and only the outer gray circle (i=20) is displayed.  And, when the remote host is up initializeSurface() followed quickly by drawPoint() are called and no gray circles but only green dots are displayed.  Code is below, followed by the 2 screen shots described before.

```
package com.balaguru.ggdiagram;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

class ToastThread implements Runnable {
    private String ivMessage;
    private View ivView;
    ToastThread(View pView, String pMessage) { ivView = pView; ivMessage = pMessage; }
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(ivView.getContext(), ivMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
class ConnectionThread extends Thread {

    private GGView ivGGView;

    ConnectionThread(GGView pGGView) {
        ivGGView = pGGView;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            ivGGView.initializeSurface();
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.context, "office-main", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.197", 10000);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line = input.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.equals("not connected")) {
                    ivGGView.drawPoint(0, 0, Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    String[] gg = line.split(",");
                    float x = Float.parseFloat(gg[0]);
                    float y = Float.parseFloat(gg[1]);
                    ivGGView.drawPoint(x, y, Color.GREEN);
                }
                line = input.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            StringWriter error = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(error));
            ToastThread toast = new ToastThread(ivGGView, error.toString());
            Activity activity = (Activity) ivGGView.getContext();
            activity.runOnUiThread(toast);
        }
    }
}

class GGView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder ivHolder;
    public Context ivContext;
    private int ivWidth;
    private int ivHeight;

    public GGView(Context context){
        super(context);
        ivContext = context;
        ivHolder = getHolder();
        ivHolder.addCallback(this);
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder pHolder) {}
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder pHolder) {
        ConnectionThread thread = new ConnectionThread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder pHolder, int pFormat, int pWidth, int pHeight) {}

    public void initializeSurface() {
        Canvas canvas = ivHolder.lockCanvas();
        ivWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        ivHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            canvas.drawArc(ivWidth/2 - i/20*ivHeight/2,
                ivHeight/2 - i/20*ivHeight/2,
                ivWidth/2 + i/20*ivHeight/2,
                ivHeight/2 + i/20*ivHeight/2,
                0, 360, false, paint);
        }
        ivHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    public void drawPoint(float pX, float pY, int pColor) {
        float x = pX / 20 * ivHeight/2 + ivWidth/2;
        float y = pY / 20 * ivHeight/2 + ivHeight/2;
        Canvas canvas = ivHolder.lockCanvas(
                new Rect((int) x-4, (int)y-4, (int) x+4, (int)y+4));
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(pColor);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
        ivHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    }
}


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        GGView ggView = new GGView(this);
        setContentView(ggView);
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**
If I change the for loop to go from 20 to 40 in initializeSurface() then drawArc appears to draw concentric circles when i=20 and i=40 but none other.  Screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problems: i/20 was being done as integer division and evaluating to 0 when drawing the arc.  Changing it to i/10f fixed that problem.  20f drew too many circles.  lockCanvas() returns 1 of a few buffered canvases and I was only drawing my circles on 1 of those canvases.  As a result, my subsequent calls to drawPoint() were drawing to canvases without those circles already being drawn.  To fix this I had to call lockCanvas() 3 times and draw my circles to each.  This is not a very elegant solution but it appears to work.  Corrected code below:

```
    public void initializeSurface() {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
            Canvas canvas = ivHolder.lockCanvas();
            ivWidth = canvas.getWidth();
            ivHeight = canvas.getHeight();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            Paint font = new Paint();
            font.setTextSize(16);
            font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            float width = ivWidth;
            float height = ivHeight;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, i / 10f * height / 2f, paint);
            ivHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

[image]